# Angular form control enable disable dynamically

Tags: dynamic, angular-reactive-forms, form-control, isenabled

I want to enable/disable the reactive form control dynamically.

I have tried below options: `formArray.controls[index].at[index].get(controlname).enable()`

or basically `formcontrol.enable()`

it changes below attribute of control: Status: 'VALID' and Enable: true

but the control is still not editable.

Can anyone please suggest how to make it editable dynamically.

// disabling on load 
`controlName: new FormControl({ value: 0, disabled: item.amount> 0 ? false : true }),`

//trying to enable on change of amount: let fg = `formarray[1].at(formgroupindex); fg.get('controlName').enable();`

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
formArray.controls[index].controls.controlName.enable()
formArray.controls[index].controls.controlName.disable()
```